# How to extract RTSP link from youtube feeds

Tags: php, json, parsing, youtube

Let say we've youtube video id

```
$vid = "g6Sji2R1kkQ";
```

then using feeds like

```
$vfeed="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$vid";
```

or also can use

```
$vfeed="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=$vid&format=1&alt=json";
```

both link shows a lot of data such as title,keywords,description ...etc

within that data there is `RTSP` link (video link for smartphone).

how to parse any of this `gdata` links to extract the `rtsp` link

i want to get it for the above id example the rtsp link should be

```
rtsp://v1.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQlEknVki6OkgxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Zend` `GData` library

```
$youtube = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();

//Grab Video data
$videoEntry = $youtube->getVideoEntry('video_code');

foreach ($videoEntry->mediaGroup->content as $content)
  if ($content->type === "video/3gpp")
    echo 'Mobile RTSP link: ' . $content->url . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know more about `json` so i've used the first feed link
i've found good function that helps me to get the results as array

```
function getvinfo($url){
$string = @file_get_contents($url);
if(!$string){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0');
$string = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
return $string;
}
```

then i'll parse the resulting `array` to get `media:content` to get `rtsp` link